# How to create Global variable in Angular for multiple Components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to create a global variable which is of type boolean, I wanted to utilize the same variable in multiple components (**Without using Service**).To be precise I also wanted to capture the variable value from any component if it is changed in other components.

Comment: you need to use a service, you can store the variable in the localStorage or in the sessionStorage but use a service

Answer (score 0):

try declaring the variable in environment.ts file